# What are the benefits of using yield as asynchronous control flow?

Tags: javascript, async-await, yield, control-flow

Angular's [Service worker](https://github.com/angular/service-worker-builds/blob/master/ngsw-worker.js) uses `yield` for asynchronous control flow. Every generator function is then passed to this function:

```
var __awaiter = (undefined && undefined.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(result.value); }).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
```

Which is pretty similar to Babel's `_asyncToGenerator`

```
function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
    return function () {
        var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            function step(key, arg) {
                try {
                    var info = gen[key](arg);
                    var value = info.value;
                } catch (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    return;
                }
                if (info.done) {
                    resolve(value);
                } else {
                    return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) {
                        return step("next", value);
                    }, function (err) {
                        return step("throw", err);
                    });
                }
            }

            return step("next");
        });
    };
}
```

What are the benefits of using `yield` for asynchronous control flow? I saw absolutely no difference between `yield` and `await` in terms of browser support on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com).

### In other terms

What's the point using this:

```js
var __awaiter = (undefined && undefined.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(result.value); }).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};

__awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    const foo = yield 3;
    const bar = yield new Promise(resolve => resolve(7));
    const baz = bar * foo;
    console.log(baz);
});
```

Instead of this:

```js
(async function () {
    const foo = await 3;
    const bar = await new Promise(resolve => resolve('7'));
    const baz = bar * foo;
    console.log(baz);
})();
```

Given this:

- [ES6 generators support](https://caniuse.com/#search=generator)
- [Async function support](https://caniuse.com/#search=await) (absolutely no difference)

Comment: "What are the benefits of using yield for asynchronous control flow" - yield is not used for asynchronous control flow, it is used with generators to [fetch the next element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield). You're confusing two different topics.

Comment: I read it carefully. Still, it could be that I didn't understand. Please explain further then!

Comment: I know what `yield` does, if you read Angular's service worker code, you'll notice that every `yield` and `function*` could be replaced with `async/await`. It's native and doesn't need a helper function like `__awaiter`

Comment: Again, yield is not relevant. The `__awaiter` function indeed uses a generator, but it also uses promises (which can be replaced by async/await). AFAIK you cannot replace async/await with generators (without using promises or callbacks).

Comment: `yield` is ES6 syntax, `await` is ES7, less browsers support ES7 natively compared to ES6

Comment: @Twistingnether If someone is misreading your post, it's often because your post is confusing in some manner, rather than the reader not reading closely. You should consider it an opportunity to edit your question so there can be no confusion.

Comment: @HereticMonkey many people didn't get confused though

Comment: @Twistingnether the thing is... I didn't get confused :)

Comment: @Ferrybig then caniuse.com is wrong?

Comment: He is correct but that's hardly related... The point is that yield is not a substitute to await.

Comment: Edited my post to clarify

Answer (score 1):

The difference comes down the the fact that Promises are meant to perform 1-off tasks, where generators are designed to repeat a task until the list of tasks has been exhausted.  If the list never exhausts, then the generator will continue as if it were a non-time-based (`setInterval()`) iterator that can pause between operations.

This can been seen in the  MDN example for a generator:

```js
function* idMaker() {
  var index = 0;
  while (true)
    yield index++;
}

var gen = idMaker(); // "Generator { }"

console.log(gen.next().value); // 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
```

It the `while` loop produced a Promise object, it would be similar to the source samples you provided. The generator would then produce a **control flow for async operations** by producing the Promise objects repeatedly as they are needed.

The logic you provided in your samples simply pushes this scenario a bit further by fulfilling the Promise contract when required.